# Capture arguments to a callback in google mock

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I have an object which has a method like this:

```
mockObj.foo(cb);
```

where cb is a function of the following signature:

```
void cb(vector<A> &, vector<B> &);
```

Is there any way to capture the 2 arguments passed to cb to see if the function did what I wanted it to do? I expect `cb` to be called `N` number of times.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test what `Obj` class is doing - unit test `Obj` class in separation, like (of course I know real `Obj::cb` is not clearing input - this is just an example):

```
TEST(ObjTest, shouldResetInput)
{
    vector<A> aa(1);
    vector<B> bb(1);
    Obj objUnderTest;
    objUnderTest.cb(aa, bb);
    ASSERT_TRUE(aa.empty());
    ASSERT_TRUE(bb.empty());
}
```

In other objects, where `Obj` is used, inject it as `ObjMock` and just check only that this `cb` function is called with input as you expect - check input by [Container Matchers](https://github.com/google/googlemock/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CheatSheet.md#container-matchers). If you want in this clients of `Obj` change the input after the function is called - use [Side Effect Actions](https://github.com/google/googlemock/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CheatSheet.md#side-effects).